# C++ and Objective-C memory management advice

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, shared-ptr

I use shared_ptr as an instance variable in Objective-C class. So I want to know if memory management is correct.

```
@interface MyClass () {
    @private
    std::shared_ptr<vector<pair<pair<float, float>, pair<float, float>>>> _periods; // In real code I use typedefs
}
```

Objects of this class lives long and happy life. But I must overwrite `_periods` often.

First I create initial `_periods` in `init` with helper function which looks like this.

```
shared_ptr<vector<pair<pair<float, float>, pair<float, float>>>> periodsScaled(...)
{
    auto periods = std::make_shared<RALG::periods>();
    // ... fill pairs of points
    return periods;
}
```

Then in `MyClass` I have `generatePeriods` function which overwrites  instance variable.

```
- (void)generatePeriods
{
    _periods.reset(); // Should I really use reset here to delete existing periods?
    _periods = periods(...);
}
```

Also I have `-dealloc` implementation

```
- (void)dealloc;
{
    _periods.reset(); // Should I reset shared pointer in dealloc?
    // other class-specific routines
}
```

Is my code correct in terms of shared_ptr memory management? I am quite new to C++

Comment: Why use `std::shared_ptr` at all?

Comment: Before that I used value sematics, just created local "periods" in helper function, returned and stored it in property with simple = assignment. Was it ok?

Comment: Yeah that's fine.  You generally only use `std::shared_ptr` on objects you create using `new`.